# Windows Terminal Keeps Crashing when Terminal Bell Sounds (MMDevAPI.DLL)

Tags: windows-10, windows-terminal

Windows terminal repeatedly clashes when the terminal bell sound goes off. On my Windows 10 machine this is 100% reproducible by using an Ubuntu shell in Windows Terminal (release and preview release) by starting Vim and using the arrow keys to trigger the bell. After several bells sound, the terminal application crashes with no error message, but the error can be found in the Event Viewer, looks like this:

```
Faulting application name: WindowsTerminal.exe, version: 1.10.2107.12003, time stamp: 0x60ecd68c
Faulting module name: MMDevAPI.DLL, version: 10.0.19041.1023, time stamp: 0x00c1ffe2
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000001b33b
Faulting process ID: 0x2b0c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d79298aae18b20
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminalPreview_1.10.1933.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\WindowsTerminal.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MMDevAPI.DLL
Report ID: e2bccc73-42d1-412c-8e97-45c3e19e5303
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.WindowsTerminalPreview_1.10.1933.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a reproducible crash and has been raised with Microsoft and confirmed as a bug [here](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/10957). The crash appears to be directly related to the presence of Sonic Studio 3 (if that doesn't sound familiar, it often bundled with RealTek audio drivers). There are two workarounds for this:

1. Turn off the audible sounds from the system bell (Settings >> Defaults >> Advanced >> Bell Notification Style):

[image: bell notification set to flash]

(This is for all shells/terminals, you can also turn it off for the specific shell if you wish)

2. Uninstall Sonic Studio/Radar (Start >> Add or Remove Programs >> Search for Sonic)

With this done terminal will no longer crash, though any re-installation or updates of drivers may cause a re-occurrence of the issue. It is on the backlog for the Windows Terminal team to fix, but given that it is largely caused by 3rd party software it may not be completely solvable from their side alone.

Comment: confirmed works on Windows 11 as well.